# Test for letters only in javascript validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Although I have my php validation doing this, thought I may as well pop it in to javascript validation too, just to pick it up before I force a page reload.

I want to test if an input has only letters in it. I have had a look around and cant get a concise block of code to use. Any help would be great.

```
var x = $('firstName').val();
var onlyLetters = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(myString);
if (x != onlyLetters) { display error; } return true;
```

I'm still new to javascript which is why I cant see why the above code isn't working. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.test()` returns a boolean true/false result. You then compare this true/false to the original string you tested, which will fail. It should be

```
if (!onlyletters) { display error; }
```

since it's already a boolean value.

Comment: You'll also need to change `.test(myString)` with `.test(x)` (since that's the variable you're testing).